# Two table recursive lookup without hierarchy, is this possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression, recursive-query

This is the current design of the SQL Server database I am working with.

I have two tables:

1. recipes

[image]

2. recipe ingredients

[image]

Recipes consist of recipe ingredients but an ingredient can be another recipe. In theory there are infinite levels as each recipe can have another ingredient that is also a recipe.

In the above data example, the Fresh Salsa recipe (ID 3047) has 7 ingredients. Six are raw Materials but one is another recipe (Recipe ID 3008). This recipe ID references another recipe in the 'recipes' table.

There is no hierarchy and I don't think I can create a hierarchy.

The goal is to extract all the recipe items for a particular recipe that have a 'sub' recipes and 'sub-sub' recipes etc.

It would seem like a recursive lookup would be the answer but because there is no hierarchy, this doesn't seem to work.

Here's my attempted query (the recipeItem list variable is a list of all the recipeitems that are also recipes created in a previous query):

```
<cfquery name="whatever">

WITH MenuPrepOfPreps (recipe_id, depth, otherRecipe_id, recipe_name)
AS

(
    SELECT r.recipe_id, 
    0 as depth,
    ri.otherRecipe_id,
    r.recipe_name 
    FROM menu_recipes r
    JOIN menu_recipeItems ri
        ON ri.otherRecipe_id = r.recipe_id
    WHERE ri.otherRecipe_id in (#recipeItemList#)
    UNION ALL
-- recursive members
    SELECT 
    mop.recipe_id,
    mop.depth + 1 as depth,
    ri.otherRecipe_id,
    r.recipe_name
    FROM menu_recipes r
    JOIN menu_recipeItems ri
        ON ri.otherRecipe_id = r.recipe_id
    INNER JOIN MenuPrepOfPreps AS MOP
        ON ri.otherRecipe_id = MOP.recipe_id
        
)

SELECT top(6)recipe_id, recipe_name
FROM MenuPrepOfPreps
GROUP BY recipe_id, recipe_name

</cfquery>
```

It keeps creating an infinite loop. When I limit the results to the first few rows (top 6), it does give the desired result.

It is possible that the design of the database is not correct so this might never work.

Any help is appreciated.

[UPDATED QUERY BASED ON @NewBie20200101 PROPOSED SOLUTION WITH CHANGES TO VARIABLE/COLUMN NAMES]

```
<cfquery name="whatever">

WITH MenuPrepOfPreps AS

(
    SELECT otherrecipe_id, 
    CASE 
        when 
            otherRecipe_id = 0 then null 
        else 
            otherRecipe_id 
        end 
        as sub_recipe 

    FROM menu_recipeItems as a -- anchor

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    a.otherrecipe_id,
    CASE 
        when
            b.otherRecipe_id = 0 then null 
        else
            b.otherRecipe_id 
        end 
        as sub_recipe
    FROM menu_recipeItems as b
    where b.recipe_id = a.otherRecipe_id --recursion
    and a.otherRecipe_id is null --stopper      
), allrecipeitems as (

SELECT recipe_id, sub_recipe
FROM MenuPrepOfPreps
)

Select
 c.recipe_id,
 d.otherRecipe_id
 From MENU_recipes c
 INNER JOIN MENU_recipeItems d on c.recipe_id = d.otherRecipe_id
 Where c.recipe in (#recipelist#)

</cfquery>
```

Does not work and gives the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "a.otherRecipe_id" could not be bound.

Comment: Do you have anything to protect from cycles in your recipe graph?

Comment: I don't think so, that's why I think this is not working... it just keeps looping and returns a huge or infinite result set for some reason

Comment: Aren't you going in the wrong direction anyway. You are currently starting with the recipes at the bottom of the tree and going back up, sounds like your list of recipes are the root recipes?

Comment: The join in the recursive part doesn't make sense. It's joining twice on `otherRecipe_id`

Comment: That's where I think it fails but if I have a list that I am selecting from, I don't know how to do that unless I loop over the list and run the query as many times as the list is long, which wouldn't make sense. 

I am not sure what you mean by 'wrong direction' is it just a matter of setting the 'IN' clause somewhere else? In the recursive member part? But then it would select all recipes, not the ones I want? As you can see, I am not clear.

Comment: Wrong direction meaning: do you have a list of base recipes that you want to know which other recipes contain them? Because that's what your code tries to do now. I would imagine you actually have a list of recipes that you want to know all other recipes they contain

Comment: Yes, I have a list of recipes and I need to know what other recipes are needed to make that first list. The recipeItemList is the list of recipes that I need to find the sub-recipes for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out myself with help from all contributors (thank you). First off as was mentioned by @Charlieface I was approaching this from the wrong direction. With this solution I started from the bottom of the hierarchy and worked up until there is no more data to get in the hierarchy.

The last query has multiple filters and grouping in order to get exactly the information I need.

If anyone is interested, here's the solution:

```
WITH MenuPrepOfPreps (recipe_id, otherRecipe_id, depth, recipe_name)

AS (
SELECT
    mria.recipe_id, mria.otherRecipe_id, 0, mr.recipe_name
FROM 
    menu_recipeItems mria, menu_recipes mr
where 
    mria.otherrecipe_id <> 0
    and mria.recipe_id = mr.recipe_id

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    MenuPrepOfPreps.recipe_id, mri.otherrecipe_id, MenuPrepOfPreps.depth+1, mr.recipe_name
FROM 
    menu_recipeItems mri, MenuPrepOfPreps, menu_recipes mr
WHERE MenuPrepOfPreps.otherrecipe_id = mri.recipe_id 
    AND MRI.otherrecipe_id <> 0
    AND mr.recipe_id = mri.recipe_id
)

SELECT 
    mopsA.otherrecipe_id, mopsA.recipe_id, mopsA.depth, mra.recipe_name AS thePrepRecipeName
FROM 
    MenuPrepOfPreps mopsA, MENU_recipes MRA
WHERE 
    mopsA.recipe_id in (#recipelist#)
    AND mopsA.otherRecipe_id = MRA.recipe_id 
    AND MRA.recipeType_id = 2
GROUP BY mra.recipe_name, mopsA.otherrecipe_id, mopsA.recipe_id, mopsA.depth
```

I will have to see how this behaves with a larger dataset than the sample set I have now, but so far it's pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a table valued function that returns all leaf `recipeItem` for a single `recipe_id` (that flattens the hierarchy), without a recursion but a loop that resolves one recursion level at a time (instead of following each single branch). If you have a million sub recipes down to 10 levels deep it takes 12 iterations to get the data (10 (the depth) + 1 (determines nothing has changed anymore) + 1 (to get all the leaves from the recipes).

This approach has also the advantage that no limit must be set, if there is an endless loop defined in the database it does not bother us the slightest.

Here the code for the table valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRecipeItemsFlat](@recipe_id INT)
RETURNS @recipeItems TABLE (recipeItem_id INT NOT NULL)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @recipeList TABLE (recipe_id INT);
  DECLARE @previousCount INT = 0;
  DECLARE @currentCount INT = 1;
  -- Get all recipe_ids recursively until infinity (no endless loop possible)
  INSERT INTO @recipeList SELECT @recipe_id;
  WHILE (@previousCount < @currentCount) BEGIN
    -- Adding not yet added child recipe_ids 
    INSERT INTO @recipeList SELECT DISTINCT otherRecipe_id FROM recipeItem WHERE recipe_id IN (SELECT recipe_id FROM @recipeList) AND (otherRecipe_id IS NOT NULL) AND (otherRecipe_id != 0) AND (otherRecipe_id NOT IN (SELECT recipe_id FROM @recipeList));
    SET @previousCount = @currentCount ;
    SET @currentCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @recipeList);
  END
  INSERT INTO @recipeItems SELECT recipeItem_ID FROM recipeItem WHERE recipe_id IN (SELECT * FROM @recipeList) AND (rawMaterial_id IS NOT NULL) AND (rawMaterial_id != 0);
  RETURN;
END
```

And then I would create a view that provides all leaf `recipeItem` for a `recipe` like this:

```
CREATE VIEW recipeItemFlat
AS
SELECT c.recipe_id, c.recipeItem_id, c.ItemQuantity, c.rawMaterial_id 
  FROM recipe a 
  CROSS APPLY dbo.GetRecipeItemsFlat(recipe_id) b 
  INNER JOIN recipeItem c ON b.recipeItem_id = c.recipeItem_id;
```

And then the query to get all items for recipe 3047 is trivial:

```
SELECT * FROM recipeItemFlat WHERE recipe_id = 3047
```

There is one possible issue with this solution which I usually use for rights and roles resolutions and such things where it does not matter but here it could:

If there is a recipe A that has two recipes B and C and both B and C have a recipe D, then D is going to be only once in the result and adding up the quantities would give a wrong result. If that is relevant, don't use `DISTINCT` to determine the end of the loop in the table valued function but a maximum level like you did in your example.

Comment: I also noticed that you use 0 in the `otherRecipe_id` if there is none. I would also use `null` like you do in column `rawMaterial_id` and then set a custom constraint like this:

    ALTER TABLE dbo.recipeItem ADD CONSTRAINT
 recipeItem_CK01 CHECK (((otherRecipe_id IS NULL) AND (rawMaterial_id IS NOT NULL)) OR
((otherRecipe_id IS NOT NULL) AND (rawMaterial_id IS NULL)))
GO

Comment: I'm definitely going to try this solution as well and post here with results... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is gonna work:

```
With preppreprep as (
    Select     
        Recipeid,    
        Case when otherrecipeId = 0 then null else otherrecipeID end as otherrecipeID, ——remove 0 it might be a problem    
    From 
    Recipeitems as a ——————anchor    
     Left outer join recipeitems as b on a.otherrecipeID = b.recipeID
    Union all

    Select
        C.recipeid,    
        Case when c.otherrecipeID = 0 the null else c.other recipeID end as otherrecipeID, also remove 0    
    From preprepprep as c 
    Left outer join recipeitems as d
    Where c.recipeid = d.otherrecipeID———--recursion   
), allrecipeitems as (
    Select    
        RecipeID,
        OtherrecipeID
    From preprepprep    
)
Select
    C.RecipeID
    D.OtherRecipeID
From recipe c
Inner recipeitems d on c.recipeid = d.recipeid
Where c.recipe in (##)
——extract unpacked sub recipes based on recipe
```

If you think there are more than 99 levels, add option max recursion 0

Comment: Not sure if I understand where this would run? Is this the whole query without recursion?

Comment: Sorry this is my first attempt answering questions lol. This replace your whole query but you need to change the words. Recursion happens within the brackets. It will should keep joining until nothing to join(that’s why changed 0 to null) and outside the brackets you simply select everything out

Comment: Ok, I will try this after my bike ride... :)

Comment: Going to bed :) I’ll check post again when I’m up see how you are doing

Comment: @NewBie20200101 please check out the code formatting options in the editor and ensure your queries are easily readable. Also please ensure you explain what you have done, rather than just writing a query, that way OP learns the thinking behind the solution.

Comment: @NewBie20200101 I think this is headed in the right direction but this query does not query the table 'recipes', it only queries itself. This is why I had joins in my first attempt. It must fetch the 'otherRecipe_id' from the 'recipes' table... let me see if I can incorporate the join and I will post.

Comment: What about putting my final select in another CTE (say allrecipeitem), and in the final select you select from recipe inner join allrecipeitems

Comment: I updated the answer sections. Also than you Dale.

Comment: @NewBie20200101 Thanks for your help in trying to solve this problem/ Unfortunately my understanding of recursive queries/CTE is obviously limited but the sample query you wrote doesn't appear to fetch or link the correct ids.

I have tried to follow your solution with what I believe to be the corrected references but  it doesn't work (or, at least, it gives an error)... please have a look and see if what I did is correct. As mentioned by DaleK, it would really help to explain what your solution does so that I can match with my scenario or where your solution may need to be tweaked.

Comment: Could you name the otherrecipeid (because in A you didn’t give it a new name after the case)

Comment: @NewBie20200101 Whether I give it a name or not, the error as described in the post persists. 'a.otherRecipe_id could not be bound'

Comment: I’m so sorry about the bad suggestions. I don’t have a laptop to try the code.. if you don’t mind I’ll check again tomorrow in mssql. Meanwhile could you try to change B from “recipeitems” table to preppreprep? Thanks

Comment: Sorry Buddy, I will work on getting you a working result first thing tomorrow. I will delete my answer and hopefully someone else more capable could answer it.

Comment: And in A Change “ sub_recipe” to “ otherRecipe_id”

Comment: @NewBie20200101 have you been able to look at this more? I have still not been able to make this work. I coded a limited hard-coded recursive lookup but it will run into issues after 4 levels.

Comment: Could you try the updated answer? If it doesn’t work I hope you could delete my answer and try again hope someone more capable can help... sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @NewBie20200101 Dude! You are not wasting my time... you are helping me and I appreciate it. I have tried your last solution and (after some clean-up :D) it runs without errors but it doesn't do recursive lookup the way I need it to. In fact, it just displays returns the same as 

'select * from recipe_items where recipe_id IN (#recipelist#)'