# Retrieve cyclic graph data without infinite loop and repeated

Tags: sql, vb.net, loops, graph, common-table-expression

I need to query these records to get unique related items:

```
insert into items(child, parent) 
values (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5), (3, 4),
       (4, 5), (6, 7), (1, 8), (8, 1)
```

I need to pass the input e.g. 1 and get result of related items

```
 2 3 4 5 8
```

I tried with SQL / CTE but I failed.

So, I need any solution with VB.NET or SQL help, with big data considered ..

============ Add Query

```
 WITH Alter_RC AS ( 
      SELECT sa1.child,
          sa1.parent,
          CAST(concat(LOWER( sa1.child), ',', LOWER( sa1.parent)) as  nvarchar(MAX)) as relpath
          FROM items sa1
          WHERE LOWER( sa1.child ) =   LOWER(  '1'  )
    UNION ALL
       SELECT  sa1.child,
           sa1.parent,
           CAST( concat(sa2.relpath, ',', sa1.parent) as nvarchar(MAX)) as relpath
           FROM Alter_RC as sa2 inner join items as sa1 on sa2.parent = sa1.child
           where LOWER( sa1.parent  ) NOT IN  (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(relpath, ','))
     )
     SELECT  parent FROM  Alter_RC  
     OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Output

```
2 8 3 5 4 5
```

Comment: _"I tried with SQL / CTE but I failed."_ - **Show us** your CTE query.

Comment: I tried many other queries and I added one of them... I don't need any solution with select distinct.. becauase when I have big data, the performance will be bed so bad ..

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of SARGability?

Comment: no, but if it could help me, no problem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean

Comment: could you help me by writing example?

Comment: ...I don't think you really understood what I just said. There is no example to give, I'm explaining why your query is slow.

Comment: if you mean something like this: where LOWER( sa2.relpath  )  NOT LIKE '%' + CAST(sa1.parent AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '%' .. it gets me same result ..

Comment: The main problem, check the example the cycling in sibiling so it is much more difficult to detect in cte

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: I posted a solution here which is quite efficient for group-in-group resolution etc. It probably does not scale without rewriting a bit, but could hint you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082516/two-table-recursive-lookup-without-hierarchy-is-this-possible/66191516#comment117061180_66191516

Comment: from can I get #recipelist#??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the problem with VB.NET because I need to check repeated items, as follow:

```
Dim relateditems As New List(Of String)

Private Sub RetreiveItems(item As String)
    Dim watch As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    relateditems.Add(item)
    Dim Where = " LOWER( sa1.child ) = LOWER('" & item & "' ) "
    RecursivelyRetreiveItems(Where) 
    watch.Stop() 
    Console.WriteLine(relateditems.Count & " " & watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
End Sub

Private Sub RecursivelyRetreiveItems(Where As String)
    Dim dt = selectSQLData("SELECT sa1.child as currentItem, sa1.parent as parentItem  FROM items sa1 WHERE " & Where & " and fitem_Different_yn = '0' ").Tables(0)

    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        If relateditems.Contains(dt.Rows(i)("parentItem").ToString) = False Then
            relateditems.Add(dt.Rows(i)("parentItem"))
        End If
    Next

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim newWhere = "("
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            If newWhere <> "(" Then
                newWhere += " OR "
            End If
            newWhere += "LOWER(sa1.child) = LOWER('" & dt.Rows(i)("parentItem") & "' ) "
        Next
        newWhere += ") and (" & ("'" + String.Join(",", relateditems) + "'") & " not LIKE concat('%', sa1.parent, '%')     ) "

        RecursivelyRetreiveItems(newWhere)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using recursive CTE in SQL server. Please give it a try. I am not sure how effective it would be. But surely it will give you the answer you are looking for.

```
with main_cte as
    (
    select distinct
        case when parent > child then child 
            else parent end as child , 
        case when parent < child then child 
            else parent end as parent
    from items
    ) ,            
cte as
    (
        select  child , parent from main_cte as a
        union all
        select  a.child , b.parent from cte as a inner join main_cte as b on a.parent = b.child
    ),
base_cte as
    (
        select parent as child , child as parent from main_cte as a
    ),
next_cte as
    (
        select child , parent from base_cte as a
        union all
        select b.child , a.parent from next_cte as a inner join base_cte as b on a.child = b.parent
        union all
        select b.child , a.child from next_cte as a inner join base_cte as b on a.parent = b.parent
    ) , 
final_cte as
(
    select child as person  , parent as relatives from
    (
        select child , parent from cte 
        union all
        select child , parent from next_cte 
        where child <> parent
    ) as a
    group by child , parent
)
select person , string_agg(cast(relatives as varchar(1)) , ',') as realtives from final_cte group by person;
```

Comment: excution isn't stopping !, where can I add: where child =   LOWER(  '1'  ) ?

Comment: apply to this to check:  CREATE TABLE ##test (
           child  nvarchar(50), 
     parent  nvarchar(50)
     ) 

insert into ##test ( child, parent) 
        values (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5), (3, 4),
       (4, 5), (6, 7), (1, 8), (8, 1)
----
For specific item

Comment: So you need the output for a specific input? where child = 1? This is possible, but what I don't understand is the last record. If the parent of 1 is 8, then how the reverse is going to be possible? - Please explain. So if you remove the last record, then you can get your desired output. Let me know if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: The main problem in these records because of cyclic results in multiple way… especially if the same parent in two different siblings… actually, real data more complex

Comment: I get it. Because of the above complex records, the query will try to join with every possible combinations within the data. But surely, it will give you the desired results. anyway, let me think something else.

Comment: To answer your question, the table represents items relationships.. so A could be related to B, and reverse..what I need when I choose any item I should  get all related items and related of related without repeating or cycling.. if your example is working correctly please explain to me what’s wrong

Comment: Can you please run the above query and see if this works? Let me know if you get the desired data. This solution should work in SQL server. I think I have already said that. Apologies for the delayed response.

Comment: I tried your query for many example, I got infinite excusion

Comment: In the end you can filter also for which member you want. like this where child = LOWER( '1' ).

Comment: You ran the above one? I just now edited the code. Please try now.

Comment: Let me know if you get the answer with the above query. Anyway, your solution is pretty impressive.

Comment: In the updated solution you supposed the item is always number with sequnce relationship but actually, it's not neccesary : case when parent > child

Comment: Okay understood. Is this working? Because I did not see what data you have. I was just trying the do it on the datasets you'd supplied.